# iOS PDF generation, how to set all restrictions

Tags: ios, pdf, pdf-generation

I have a problem, I am generating PDF by using some low level CG and UI functions, everything is done by code and the document it self looks good. The problem is in Document Permissions. I do the following :

```
  CGPDFDocumentRef PDFref = loadPDFAtPath([filePath UTF8String]);
  CGPDFPageRef pageRef = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(PDFref, 1);

    NSString *encPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-enc.pdf", filePath];
    CFStringRef pathNew = (__bridge CFStringRef)encPath;
    CFURLRef url = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath(NULL, pathNew, kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle, 0);

    CFMutableDictionaryRef myDictionary = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(NULL, 0,
                                                                    &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks,
                                                                    &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);
    CFStringRef refPassword = (__bridge CFStringRef)password;
    CFStringRef creatorRef = (__bridge CFStringRef)@"CREATOR";
    CFStringRef authorRef = (__bridge CFStringRef)@"TEST";
    CFStringRef titleRef = (__bridge CFStringRef)@"TEST1";

    CFDictionarySetValue(myDictionary, kCGPDFContextCreator, creatorRef);
    CFDictionarySetValue(myDictionary, kCGPDFContextAuthor, authorRef);
    CFDictionarySetValue(myDictionary, kCGPDFContextTitle, titleRef);
    CFDictionarySetValue(myDictionary, kCGPDFContextOwnerPassword, refPassword);
    CFDictionarySetValue(myDictionary, kCGPDFContextAllowsCopying, kCFBooleanFalse);

    CGRect prescriptionBounds = [PrescriptionMaker receiptBounds];
    CGContextRef ref = CGPDFContextCreateWithURL(url, &prescriptionBounds, myDictionary);
    CGPDFContextBeginPage(ref, myDictionary);
    CGContextDrawPDFPage(ref, pageRef);
    CGPDFContextEndPage(ref);
    CGContextRelease(ref);
```

In Adobe software I can see my changes

[Adobe Acrobat Reader DC settings window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TR2m0.png)
My question is how to set all the rest of the permission settings (Commenting, Signing, Filling of forms fields, Creation of template pages). Right now they are all set to "Allowed" and I want them to be "Not Allowed" except printing. I couldn't find the corresponding keys in the Auxiliary Dictionary Keys in Apple Documentation.

Thanks for help.

Comment: any luck solving this or getting this in swift ?

Comment: Not really, but I did manage to overcome this issue in a obj-c project by using QPDF c++ lib.